# Can i have if statement inside a Template Match= in xslt

Tags: xslt

I want acheive 3 things.

First is rename the GroupArea to GroupBox Nodes.

Second is Put a  tag after the GroupBox and GroupArea Node.

Third is to move all child GroupArea and GroupBox Nodes and its content to ParentNode of XML. To acheive this i am using 2 template match and this is messing up things.

I cannot upload an image to show this for now.

If i can put a If-else logic inside the first templateMatch then i should be fine. I think i cannot do that. But by using 2 of them, the line  "xsl:apply-templates select="node()" in the second templateMatch is coping over the entire node including child GroupArea to a GroupArea instead of just renaming the GroupArea to GroupBox.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
<xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>


<!--First Template Match. To Move all the child GroupArea and GroupBox to Parent and inject a Blank Controls Tag-->
<xsl:template match="GroupBox|GroupArea">
<xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*[not(self::GroupBox | self::GroupArea )]" />
<GroupBox>
<Controls>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[not(self::GroupBox | self::GroupArea )]" />  
    </Controls>
</GroupBox>
</xsl:copy>
<xsl:apply-templates select="GroupBox|GroupArea|GROUPAREA|GROUPBOX" />
</xsl:template>



<!--Second Template Match. To Convert all the GroupArea to GroupBox and then Inject the Blank Control Tags-->
<xsl:template match="GroupArea">
<GroupBox>
<xsl:apply-templates select="@*" /> 
<Controls>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" />  
</Controls>  
</GroupBox>
</xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Is there anyway to acheive the same. XML FILE Below

```
<MyControls>
<GroupBox Id="GroupBox1" Title="Public Event Details">
<Textbox HasPopup="False" Id="NameOfEvent" Title="Name of Event"> </Textbox>
<GroupBox Id="ctrl_0" Title="">
<CheckBox  Title="Public Property" AccessItem="0"></CheckBox>
<Textbox HasPopup="False" Id="Location" Title="Location or Route" ></Textbox>
</GroupBox>

<GroupArea Id="ctrl_1" Title="">
<Textbox  Id="_MATaxNumber" Title="MA Tax Number"  AccessItem="0" HintText=""></Textbox>
<Textbox HasPopup="False"  Id="AttExp" Title="Attes Expected" ></Textbox>
</GroupArea>

<GroupBox Id="ctrl_2" Title=""/>

<GroupBox Id="ctrl_3" Title="">
    <CheckBox  Id="CBPublicEventDetails_VendingFood" Title="Food"  AccessItem="0"></CheckBox>
    <CheckBox  Id="CBPublicEventDetails_VendingGoods" Title="Goods" AccessItem="0"></CheckBox>
    <Textbox HasPopup="False" Id="VendingVendors" Title="Total Vendors" ></Textbox>
</GroupBox>

<GroupArea Id="ctrl_4" Title="">
<CheckBox Id="CBPuEntLiveMusic" Title="Live Music"  AccessItem="0"></CheckBox>
<CheckBox Id="CBPubliEntStage" Title="Stage" AccessItem="0"></CheckBox>
</GroupArea>

<GroupBox Id="ctrl_5" Title="">
    <CheckBox  Id="CBPublicEventDetails_GamesGames" Title="Games" AccessItem="0"></CheckBox>
    <CheckBox  Id="CBPublicEventDetails_GamesOther" Title="Other"  AccessItem="0"></CheckBox>
</GroupBox>


<GroupBox Id="ctrl_6" Title="">
<Textbox HasPopup="False"  Id="SecurityHow" Title="How will they be identified?"/>
<Textbox HasPopup="False" Id="SecurityNumber" Title="Security Personnel #"/>
</GroupBox>

<GroupBox Id="ctrl_19" Title="">
<CheckBox Id="cb_pubeventdetails_emswalk" Title="Run/Walk" AccessItem="0"></CheckBox>
<CheckBox  Id="cb_pubeventdetails_emsboat" Title="Boating/Swim" AccessItem="0"></CheckBox>



<GroupArea id="gaAdjustmentResults">
    <Grid id="gdAdjustmentResults" >
        <Columns>               
                            <GridColumn ID="gc1"  DataType="Int"></GridColumn>      
        </Columns>
    </Grid>

    <GroupArea id="gaAdjustmentNew" >
        <Grid id="gdAdjustmentResults" >
        <Columns>
            <GridColumn ID="gcAdjustment"  DataType="Int"></GridColumn> 
        </Columns>
        </Grid>
    </GroupArea>
</GroupArea>
</GroupBox>
</GroupBox>
</MyControls>
```

WHAT I AM GETTING AS OUTPUT WITH THIS XSL. SHOWING JUST THE SECTION WITH ISSUE. AT THE BOTTOM I HAVE ATTACHED THE COMPLETE TRANSFORMED XML.

WHILE USING THE XML AND XSL YOU WILL SEE BELOW RESULT SEE I HAVE A INNER GROUPBOX STILL FOUND. IF YOU REMORE THE SECOND TEMPLATEMATCH YOU WILL NOT FIND THE INNER GORUPAREA BUT IT WILL BE A GROUPAREA AND NOT A GROUPBOX

```
<GroupBox id="gaAdjustmentResults">
<Controls>
  <Grid id="gdAdjustmentResults">
    <Columns>
      <Label ID="gc1" DataType="Int">
      </Label>
    </Columns>
  </Grid>
  <GroupBox id="gaAdjustmentNew">
    <Controls>
      <Grid id="gdAdjustmentResults">
        <Columns>
          <Label ID="gcAdjustment" DataType="Int">
          </Label>
        </Columns>
      </Grid>
    </Controls>
  </GroupBox>
</Controls>
```

FURTHER IF YOU SEE THE TRANSFORMATION, IS THERE ANYWAY I CAN MOVE THE 2 GRID NODES AND ADD IT TO THE BOTTOM OF THE FILE INSIDE THE OUTER CONTROLS TAG.

Expected Output

```
<MyControls>
<GroupBox Id="GroupBox1" Title="Public Event Details">
<Controls>
  <Textbox HasPopup="False" Id="NameOfEvent" Title="Name of Event">
  </Textbox>
</Controls>
</GroupBox>
<GroupBox Id="ctrl_0" Title="">
<Controls>
  <CheckBox Title="Public Property" AccessItem="0">
  </CheckBox>
  <Textbox HasPopup="False" Id="Location" Title="Location or Route">
  </Textbox>
</Controls>
</GroupBox>
<GroupBox Id="ctrl_1" Title="">
<Controls>
  <Textbox Id="_MATaxNumber" Title="MA Tax Number" AccessItem="0" HintText="">
  </Textbox>
  <Textbox HasPopup="False" Id="AttExp" Title="Attes Expected">
  </Textbox>
</Controls>
</GroupBox>
<GroupBox Id="ctrl_2" Title="">
<Controls>
</Controls>
</GroupBox>
<GroupBox Id="ctrl_3" Title="">
<Controls>
  <CheckBox Id="CBPublicEventDetails_VendingFood" Title="Food" AccessItem="0">
  </CheckBox>
  <CheckBox Id="CBPublicEventDetails_VendingGoods" Title="Goods" AccessItem="0">
  </CheckBox>
  <Textbox HasPopup="False" Id="VendingVendors" Title="Total Vendors">
  </Textbox>
</Controls>
</GroupBox>
...........
...........

<GroupBox id="gaAdjustmentResults">
<Controls>
  <Grid id="gdAdjustmentResults">
    <Columns>
      <Label ID="gc1" DataType="Int">
      </Label>
    </Columns>
  </Grid>
</Controls>
</GroupBox>

<GroupBox id="gaAdjustmentNew">
    <Controls>
      <Grid id="gdAdjustmentResults">
        <Columns>
          <Label ID="gcAdjustment" DataType="Int">
          </Label>
        </Columns>
      </Grid>
    </Controls>
  </GroupBox>
</GroupBox>
</MyControls>
```

Comment: Please show a sample of your expected output, as well as your input.

Comment: I will soon. Thanks. Wish i could have added an image

Comment: You don't need to upload an image. Just a snippet showing the relevant parts of your code (showing the source tree that will be transformed, as well as the root, since you wish to move elements there).

Comment: I still can't understand what your expected result is. Should the controls be *inside* the `GroupBox`? You said you wanted it after it. If you post a complete example showing your expected output and how it relates to your input it would be easier to help you. In the XSL I posted, the `GroupBox` and `GroupArea` children are selected once from the root. If you apply that to your example, you won't have the problem of nested `GroupBox` elements.

Comment: If you see the example for input XMl <GroupArea id="gaAdjustmentResults">
is a GroupArea. <GroupArea id="gaAdjustmentNew" > is child of gaAdjustmentResults and its a GroupArea. After the transformation it should become a GroupBox and also become a parent. All GroupArea should become child of the outermost <MyControls> Tag. Further if you see the transformed GroupAreas they have a Extra <Control> Tag inside, which was not there in the original XML. I am attaching the expected output in the Main Post in a minute.

Comment: Just added the expected Output. The GroupArea should become GroupBox and it should be child of <MyControls>. Further is there any way i can get the Grids which are child of either GroupBox or GroupArea as child of <MyCOntrols> and add them to bottom of XML inside <MyControls>. The transformed XML has an extra <Controls> Tag as well. <MyControls> is Parent and <Control> is a injected node under all GroupBox( Transformed GroupBox which were originally GroupArea).

Comment: Yes the controls be inside the GroupBox. Further is there any way the Grid Nodes and its children can be moved to the bottom of the XML outisde all the GroupBox and inside the Parent Tag<MyControl>

Answer (score 1):

Based on what you posted, I came up with some examples which may help you find a solution. I'm assuming some things since you didn't post your input source.

All you have to do to *rename* `GroupArea` to `GroupBox` (wherever they may be in your source), and not process children which are `GroupArea` or `GroupBox` is:

```
<xsl:template match="GroupArea">
    <GroupBox>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()[not(self::GroupBox | self::GroupArea )]" />
    </GroupBox>
</xsl:template>
```

Assuming you have an identity transform somewhere:

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

the descendants and attributes will be copied to the result tree.

You also want an element *after* the `<GroupBox>` nodes. I didn't understand what you want *inside* it, so I left it empty:

```
<xsl:template match="GroupArea | GroupBox">
    <GroupBox>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()[not(self::GroupBox | self::GroupArea )]" />
    </GroupBox>
    <Controls></Controls>
</xsl:template>
```

Now, to make all your `<GroupBox>` nodes children of the document element, you just need to match a template in the document element and select your `GroupArea | GroupBox` nodes from there:

```
<xsl:template match="RootElement">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="//GroupBox | //GroupArea" />
    ...
</xsl:template>
```

Try this stylesheet. If the structure of your source is not too different from what I imagined, it might work at least as a starting point:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="RootElement">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//GroupBox | //GroupArea" />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="GroupArea | GroupBox">
        <GroupBox>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()[not(self::GroupBox | self::GroupArea )]" />
        </GroupBox>
        <Controls></Controls>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[self::GroupBox | self::GroupArea]" />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: JUST ADDED THE XML INPUT FILE. IF YOU USE THE XML AND XSLT PROVIDED YOU CAN SEE THE RESULT. I HAVE SHOWN PARTIAL OUTPUT AT END OF MY NOTE. THE LAST GROUPBOX IS A CHILD INSTEAD OF BEING A PARENT. IF I REMOVE THE SECOND TEMPLATE MATCH THE LAST ONE WILL BE POSITIONED AS DESIRED BUT IT WILL BE A GROUPAREA INSTEAD OF A GROUPBOX.

Comment: Whoa, lay off the caps lock, @user3657957.

Comment: In your template you have added <Controls> outside the GroupBox.
<Controls> should be child to the <GroubBox>. See the change.
<xsl:template match="GroupArea | GroupBox">
<GroupBox>
 <Controls>
 <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()[not(self::GroupBox | self::GroupArea )]" />
 </Controls>
 </GroupBox>
<xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()[self::GroupBox | self::GroupArea]"/>
</xsl:template>.
Now once that happens the attibutes of GroupBox are copied over to the <Control>. 
<GroupBox> <Controls Id="ctrl_0" Title=""> </Controls> </GroupBox>
I donot want that. GroupBox attributes should remain.